# pip install psycopg2 venv freezing

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-postgres, psycopg

So I'm trying to install psycopg2 in a virtualenv so that I can deploy a Django app to Herkou. I ran into a pg_config executable not found error, so I reinstalled PostgreSQL, but this time via homebrew (I just used the OSX graphical install before) hoping this would fix the error. I'm not getting that error anymore, but now when I sudo pip install psycopg2, I just get this:

```
(venv)xxxx-xxxx:project_name Brandon$ sudo pip install psycopg2
Password:
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.5.1.tar.gz (684kB): 684kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -    fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090301 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.1/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

and It just freezes there. I let it go for half an hour before canceling it. It doesn't even give me an error message, just that warning, which I assume isn't a big deal. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

From a linux command line, I get this:

```
% sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
...
% pip install psycopg2          
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.5.1.tar.gz (684kB): 684kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/error_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09010A -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -lpq -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

Successfully installed psycopg2
Cleaning up...
```

Maybe use a different compiler as your default C/C++ compiler?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: So I found a solution. I think clang was the issue, so I updated XCode and that resolved it.